# Azure Site Recovery - Disk Size Unusable message after shrinking disks

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, replication, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have a customer with a Hyper-V VM (running under a Windows 2012 R2 Hyper-V Cluster) that had drives larger than 1023GB.  When I went to replicate the VM to Azure using Azure Site Recovery I got an error message that said "Disk Size Unusable".  I then shrank all of the disks in the VM to under 1023GB (actually 1000GB or less) expecting that I could then select the VM for Site Replication.  But I still get the message "Disk Size Unusable" even after making the change two days ago.  How can I get the Azure Portal to re-query the VM and see that the drives are now all under the 1023GB limitation?
Any ideas would certainly be appreciated!
dave

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you go into the Azure portal and go into the "Recovery Services Vault - Site Recovery Infrastructure - Hyper-V Hosts - select host - Refresh Server" this will re-read the existing VM's and now I can replicate this VM with resized disks.